# Cannot install CocoaPods in React Native Turbo Module on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-turbomodule

I'm trying to install Cocoapods in a React Native Turbo Module.

```
> RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install
Could not find cocoapods-1.11.3, cocoapods-core-1.11.3, algoliasearch-1.27.5, typhoeus-1.4.0, json-2.6.2, ethon-0.15.0, ffi-1.15.5 in locally installed gems
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

These are the errors I get when I try and run `bundle install`.

```
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
      algoliasearch was resolved to 1.27.5, which depends on
        json
```